# Windows 10 Wifi Sets Wrong DNS Server When Connecting to Wifi Networks

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

Somehow my Windows 10 laptop stopped getting the correct DNS servers sent from Wifi networks.  It somehow locked `192.168.1.1` and won't accept whatever DNS IP comes from DHCP.  I have no idea how/why, and I tried everything to fix.  Any thoughts?

Tried the Wifi while sitting at a Starbucks, the office, or the Apple Store, it always put `192.168.1.1` as the DNS server instead of the correct DNS IP supplied by the DHCP router.

I tried this under Command Prompt (run as Administrator), still **did not help**:

```
netsh winsock reset
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew
```

Also rebooted several times, turned Wifi on/off, deleted known Wifi networks... nothing works.  I also tried manually setting the DNS IP when at a known Wifi place, which works, then I set back to obtain automatically, and it goes back to stuck on `192.168.1.1`.

For example, check out `ipconfig /all` output from a Starbucks, it incorrectly says `192.168.1.1` as the DNS:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 2:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205 #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 60-67-20-12-34-56
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2d12:3c21:1234:5678%23(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.31.99.119(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, May 18, 2018 9:30:43 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, May 18, 2018 10:43:47 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.31.98.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.31.98.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 308307744
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-D4-7C-E7-3C-97-0E-12-34-56
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I have the Wifi interface set to pull DNS from DHCP, see screenshots below.

[image: Wifi Network Adapter Properties]

[image: Wifi Network Adapter Properties]

Comment: What is on the WINS tab?

Comment: I went ahead and uninstalled/reinstalled the Wifi driver while connected to the Internet another way (tethered to my phone) so I could re-download the driver, and that seemed to fix the problem. Sorry I did not capture the WINS tab, but don't recall seeing anything there when I checked.

Comment: You can and should answer your own question using the "post your answer" button.

Comment: Also seeing this on Windows 10 on the last few months. Not easy to resolve. There shpuld be an answer that does not involve reinstalling the driver

Comment: @Otheus I agree... wish I knew the fix.  Otherwise, I suggest keeping a copy of your Windows laptop's Wifi driver on the laptop itself (or quickly accessible from a USB flash drive), so if it goes crazy with DNS locking, uninstall then reinstall the driver.

Comment: Can't believe we don't know where this is being stored except within the actual driver!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frustrated, I decided to try uninstalling/reinstalling the Wifi driver.  Did by:

1. Pre-downloaded the network driver from the Drivers page of my
   laptop maker (Lenovo), or having an alternative way to access the
   Internet such as tethering through my phone, so I could download the driver.
2. Device Manager, Network Adapters, right-click the wifi device, Uninstall Driver.
3. Used the downloaded driver from my laptop manufacturer, re-installed, rebooted.  Now the Wifi DNS works fine wherever I go.

I tested at 2 wifi locations (coffee shops) so far, works fine now.

Note that some public Wifi networks at coffee shops & libraries have what's called a "Captive Portal" which requires use of the DNS supplied via DHCP.  They will not work with a public DNS or fixed DNS locked in to the Wifi interface.  At such locations, new devices that join the Wifi network are redirected to a page to accept the Terms & Conditions (or log in) before being granted access to the Internet.  This is why my Wifi stopped working at coffee shops, and would not help to use a fixed DNS like 8.8.8.8.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!

For what it's worth, just uninstalling the device and reinstalling it worked for me.

Comment: Sure thing.  Also people may have luck following 4AM's solution below, by editing the registry.  Reinstalling the driver, though, may be easier if you remember to keep the driver installer program on the laptop.

Comment: It was a very annoying issue! 

To clarify, I didn't need to re-install drivers.

I Uninstalled the device in Device Manager, and then re-scanned device manager for changes. That's all. Windows Just reinstalled the same driver again to fix it.

There must be a cache somewhere on the system.

Answer (score 39):

This is an older question but I just wanted to add my answer here because this question came up when I was searching for an answer and it pointed me in the right direction.

If your nameservers point to something that you once manually entered in the TCP/IP properties, this setting is cached in the registry under

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{*interface-UUID*}\ProfileNameServer
```

where `{*interface-UUID*}` is a unique ID that is assigned to the different interfaces on the local machine. `ProfileNameServer` is a REG_SZ string that contains a space-separated list of IP addresses of the nameservers to use. This appears to override the DhcpNameServer string, which is of the same format.

I cleared the `ProfileNameServer` string and the interface in question used what was in DhcpNameServer instead, which solved my issue.

Comment: Thanks!!  I will try this next time it happens.

Comment: Awesome you found this.  I had this exact problem where I could not find out WHY it would not change my DNS servers.  Removed that value and reconnected to the wifi and it got the correct one.  Thanks so much!

Comment: In my system (Windows 10, build 1903, version 18362.592) the DNS setting is stores under the `NameServer` registry key instead of `ProfileNameServer` (which doesn't exist).

Comment: I'm on 1903 Windows Pro and my Wifi adapter still uses ProfileNameServer although every other adapter uses NameServer. This procedure worked and should be the accepted answer.The effect was immediate - I cleared the value and ipconfig/all immediate showed the correct DNS servers.

Comment: Also works on 20H2. Was struggling for months with this problem & had to set my DNS manually depending on which network. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I wanted to thank you: Turns out I was already here (perhaps years ago) because that up arrow already was blue. Many thanks, second time.

Comment: This indeed solved my problem. As a experienced Linux but novice Windows user, I wonder how did you find out those problematic registry entries?

Comment: This did not work for me in the end. I have a wrong DHCP-Server showing up in all of my wifi-networks (`192.168.10.254`) and if I delete it in the registry (`DhcpServer` and `NameServer` keys), it will show up again (`F5`) after a few seconds, or if I disable/enable wifi. It seems I cannot get rid of this wrong static dhcp server, it has been present at least since 1-2 years across updates.

Answer (score 1):

We just changed servers - meaning the old DHCP-server is shut down, and there is a new DHCP-server. Simultaneously, we changed DNS-server.
I saw the same thing here - Windows 10 hangs on to the old DNS and no matter how many dhcp release/renew or reboots or whatever - keeps the previously used IP.

I solved the matter by doing regedt32 and manually changing the values (just search for that wrong IP (in your case 192.168.1.1). The key is called DHCPdns or something similar.

I am still a little puzzled as to what the error is caused by. Since we kept the DHCP range the same, I figured it was just the matter of the PC asking to keep the IP it had already been assigned (and thus keeping all the other parameters when the DHCP-server says "yes, fine").

Answer (score 0):

My situation was slightly different but using this article helped me resolve my issue: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/your-computer-is-trying-to-use-a-dns-server-that/c8f9e28e-7bb9-439c-bfac-3a097ddc2dfd?auth=1

I was able to determine that although my ipv4 adapter settings for DNS servers was correct, DNS lookup (nslookup *someserver*) was failing because it was first using the **ipv6** DNS server adapter lookup and failing. Changing the **ipv6** adapter settings for DNS server solved the issue for me.

Note that while the answer in the Microsoft forum had useful checks and tests, it was the MiniTool.exe that provided the information that led me to the answer. I resisted trying the MiniTool.exe at first but appears to only collect all your Windows information and output into a single text file that makes it easier to review the tcp/ip and DNS information from your machine.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Normally, some DNS servers are publicly available for private or commercial use. For example, Google has a open DNS server available on 8.8.8.8.
Use this IP-address as your default DNS server instead of it being obtained automatically.

Comment: This is true that public DNS are available, but it will not work at coffee shops or with routers that require a login.  For example, modern routers at public Wifi places (especially coffee shops and libraries) use their own DNS to redirect browsers to a specific webpage to agree to terms & conditions (or log in with a password) before granting access to the Internet. In those cases, using a public DNS will block access to the Internet regardless of being connected to the Wifi until the client's browser is redirected (via DNS) and agrees to the terms of use (or logs in).